# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete widget with label/value in JSON but not showing the results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the autcomplete widget to fill a client id in a form. It will show the label, the client name, but needs to pass the id. I'm using json and this javascript code to process:

```
    $("input#clientid").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn('normal');

            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + 'projects/ajax/get_clients',
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });

            $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("normal");
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

In my PHP controller I'm printing directly some results with JSON, firebug shows me like that:

```
[{"label":"Client example","value":1},{"label":"Lorem Ipsum","value":2},{"label":"Microsoft","value":3}]
```

But the autocomplete is not showed and no error in console. When I say not showed I'm saying that there is no "div" outside the `<input />` to select a value. Sorry don't know how to express it well.

If I try a basic example from the website with no remote it's showed. I don't know what I'm doing bad.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `minLength` is misspelled (you have `minLenght`.  Probably not causing your problem, but thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @David: your right, now the minLength works fine but the div is not showing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + 'projects/ajax/get_clients',
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST", <--- //
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
```

you are setting the request type the wrong way... thats why its setting the default ajax reaquest type that is `GET`

**Update:**

is it possible for you to complete the ajax request before you use the `autocomplete` with you input field? something like

```
$.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + 'projects/ajax/get_clients',
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    xhrResponse(data);
                }
            });


function xhrResponse(data){

$("#clientid").autocomplete({
        source: function(data, response) {
            $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn('normal');

           response($.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));


            $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("normal");
        },
        minLength: 2
    });

}
```

Comment: @3nigma: hey thank you! I got it that but now I the `<div>` where results has to be showed is not showed. No error, don't know what can be.

Comment: I tried using the code u said (deleting data:request on $.ajax()). I can complete the ajax and works fine but it doesn't shows the autcomplete. I dont see why, i don't found any error. I've tried also to pass not label/value an pass only an array of json values `["Example client","Lorem ipsum","Microsoft"]`... and nothing :S

Comment: @3nigma: If I do console.log(data); (on my original code) I don't get ANYTHING, like something fails. An alert is not showed too. Edit: adding `$.ajax({error: function(data) { alert("error"); }});` the error alert is showed.

Comment: console.log(data) shows a statusText "parsererror". I'm sending Content-type: application/json, and status is 200.

Comment: @3nigma I started another question because is not directly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5014359/569908 . Thank you!