# jQuery Autocomplete Categories Select Label and Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to get the jQuery Autocomplete with categories to return the selected value to the search field and the value to a separate input field.

I have modified the data to have a value as well as label and category.

See http://jsfiddle.net/chrisk/bM7ck/

But the value is always returned to the search field instead of the label.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's how the jquery ui autocomplete works when you supply both a label and a value. If you want the label returned to the search field, then rename the value field.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/bM7ck/3/

Comment: You're welcome. I bumped you up so you should be able to give Andrew a +1 for his focus suggestion. Team effort.

Answer (score 26):

You're close, you just need to:

1. Add `return false` to the end of your `select` event handler, and
2. Add an event handler for the `focus` event so that you can override that as well, using the label instead of the value.

Here's your code updated:

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#search').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#searchval').val(ui.item.value);
        return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        return false; // Prevent the widget from inserting the value.
    }
});
```

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/q2kDU/

Comment: I have gone with Jen's fix, but have added your suggestion of focus.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I did `return false;` on my `select:` and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
        $( "#searchitems" ).autocomplete({
            source: [<?php echo $search /*example for full list in php*/?>],
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#searchitems").val(ui.item.label);
                $('#searchitemvalue').val(ui.item.value);
                window.location="#"; //location to go when you select an item
            },
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#searchitems").val(ui.item.label);
                $('#searchitemsvalue').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been nice here