# Autocomplete applying value not label to textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Im having troubles trying to get the autocomplete to work properly.

It all looks ok to me but....

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#customer-search").autocomplete({
        source: 'Customer/GetCustomerByName',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div>
<input id="customer-search" />
 </div>
@Html.Hidden("selected-customer")
```

However when I select an item from the dropdown the value is been applied to the textbox instead of the label.

What have I done wrong?

If I look at the source using firebug I can see that my hidden field is being updated correctly.

Comment: What do you see in the JSON response in Firebug?

Comment: [{"label":"Tom Smith","value":"1234"},{"label":"Tommy Smith","value":"12321"}]

Comment: See that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716266/jquery-autocomplete-categories-select-label-and-value

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The default behavior of the `select` event is to update the `input` with `ui.item.value`. This code runs *after* your event handler.

Simply return `false` or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this from occurring. I would also recommend doing something similar for the `focus` event to prevent `ui.item.value` from being placed in the `input` as the user hovers over choices:

```
$("#customer-search").autocomplete({
    /* snip */
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LCv8L/

Comment: Very useful! Didn't you mean `$("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.value);`

Comment: @juanignaciosl: No--that code is meant to update the search box with the `label` instead of the `value`.

Comment: I am storing value at db not label, So next time I want to set according lable on basis of value. What is the way of doing so?

Comment: Hey, trying to do something similar but put everything in `focus` instead of `select`. Problem is `item.value` is being set instead of `item.label`. Anyway to circumvent this?         `lookup.autocomplete({
          source: data,
          focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label)
            status.text(ui.item.value)
            submitted.text(ui.item.submitted)
            comments.html(ui.item.comments)
          }
        })`

Comment: Same here, I want label displayed, value POSTed.  I did manage to patch together a kludge involving a hidden element (similar to @Yang Zhang's answer below, but at this point it's looking like rolling my own autocomplete will be the least inelegant approach.

Answer (score 17):

Just would like to add that instead of referencing input element by "id" inside ***select*** and ***focus*** callback functions you can use ***this*** selector, like:

```
$(this).val(ui.item.label);
```

it's useful when you assign autocomplete for multiple elements, i.e. by class:

```
$(".className").autocomplete({
...
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I need to record another field 'id' in an hidden input. So I add another field in the data returned from ajax call.

```
{label:"Name", value:"Value", id:"1"}
```

And have added a 'create new' link at the bottom of the list. On click the 'create new', a modal will pop up and you can create new item from there.

```
$('#vendorName').autocomplete
    (
        {
            source: "/Vendors/Search",
            minLength: 2,
            response: function (event, ui)
            {
                ui.content.push
                ({
                    label: 'Add a new Name',
                    value: 'Add a new Name'
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui)
            {
                $('#vendorId').val(ui.item.id);
            },
            open: function (event, ui)
            {
                var createNewVendor = function () {
                    alert("Create new");
                }
                $(".ui-autocomplete").find("a").last().attr('data-toggle', 'modal').addClass('highLight');
                $(".ui-autocomplete").find("a").last().attr('href', '#modal-form').addClass('highLight');
            }
        }
    );
```

I think the point is that you can add any extra data field other than just 'label' and 'value'.

I use bootstrap modal and it can be as below:

```
<div id="modal-form" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```