# jQuery autocomplete shows value instead of label

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [jQuery-ui autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Here is how i use it

```
<form action="go.php" method="post">
    <input id="txt" type="text" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#txt').autocomplete({
         source: [{'label': 'milan', 'value': '1'}, {'label': 'minos', 'value': '2'}]
    })
</script>
```

When i type 'mi', `milan` and `minos` shows up.No problem with that. However when i focus on them with down key value of `#txt` changes to `1`(value for milan) instead of `milan`. How can i show `milan` when i focus on it. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Because the default behavior of the **select** event is to show the **value** not the **label**, so you need to simply: 
- ***return false*** as "***İsmail Hakkı Şen***" mentioned earlier.
- or you can use ***event.preventDefault()*** to prevent the default action of the event from executing and then write down what you need to do as follows:

```
$('#txt').autocomplete({
     source: [{'label': 'milan', 'value': '1'}, {'label': 'minos', 'value': '2'}],
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#txt').val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#txt').val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Please refer to "***Andrew Whitaker***" answer in this post > [Autocomplete applying value not label to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642855/autocomplete-applying-value-not-label-to-textbox) - as it is really helpful in understanding.

Answer (score 8):

you have to tell your code on focus to do something.

```
$('#txt').autocomplete({
     source: [{'label': 'milan', 'value': '1'}, {'label': 'minos', 'value': '2'}],
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
     $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to kill focus completely. i just want #txt to show label instead of value

Comment: This solution (specifically, returning false for the focus event) is useful if you don't want to show the label or the value and would rather just prefer to leave the textbox contents as-is until an item is selected.