# Jquery Autocomplete is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete in my asp.net page. when I type something in the text box it displays "No search results" message in front of text box and it doesn't display any suggestions. I haven't seen "no search results" message box in other implementation. My code is as follows.

```
var jsonObj = "[{'value':'9a8b581d-1e23-e211-a9a4-00155d01ab06','label':'CCNA'}]";

$('#<%=txtApplicationSkills.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: jsonObj            
    });
```

Comment: See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716266/jquery-autocomplete-categories-select-label-and-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `jsonObj` is wrong. Try removing the quotes `""` around it

http://jsfiddle.net/4BvGj/

Comment: Now it shows suggestions but it also displays "2 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate" message. How to remove that message ?

Comment: well, thats quite annoying. I fix that using ".ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display: none; }" in my css file. Not sure if its your case.

Comment: <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"/>

Comment: Thanks .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display: none; } is working in my case

Answer (score 2):

InPlace for this you can use this.
    var jsonObj = "[{'value':'9a8b581d-1e23-e211-a9a4-00155d01ab06','label':'CCNA'}]";

```
var jsonObj = [{'value':'9a8b581d-1e23-e211-a9a4-00155d01ab06','label':'CCNA'}];
```