# How to return both an "id" and "text"

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [AutoComplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to search by name. I'm able to output the names, but after submitting the form, I would like to pass the `emp_id` value, not the `fullname`. How can I modify it to get the `emp_id` value, not the `fullname`?

I would like it after I submit the form I get the `emp_id` not the `fullname` value.

**search_employee.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="queryNames" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="searchPhrase" />

        <cfquery name="query_names"  datasource="">
            SELECT  fullname ,emp_id ....
        </cfquery>

        <cfset result = arrayNew(1) />

        <cfloop query="query_names">
            <cfset ArrayAppend(result, query_names.fullname) />

        </cfloop>


        <cfreturn result />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.gettingName').autocomplete({

            source: function(query, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.cfc?method=queryNames&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        searchPhrase: query.term
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        response(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: What's your plan for when two employees have the same name?

Comment: @DanBracuk not sure what you mean, emp_id is unique

Comment: @anatp_123 emp_id X and Y could each have different users with the same first and last names.

Comment: In other words, if emp_id's 1 and 2 were both named John Smith, and the user searched for John Smith, how does your code know which one the user wants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean display the "FullName" selected, but store its ID in another form field?

Add a form field for storing the "id":

```
  <input id="gettingName">
  <input id="theValue">
```

Modify the component to return an array of structures. Each structure containing two keys named "value" (id) and "label" (fullName).

```
<cfloop query="local.query_names">
    <cfset local.data = {"value": emp_id, "label": fullName}>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(local.result, local.data) />
</cfloop>
```

In the javascript, use the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to [update the values of the two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717445/8895292).

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#gettingName').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#theValue').val(ui.item.value);
    return false; 
},
```

Comment: doest work correctly, i change it to <cfset data = {"value"= emp_id, "label"=fullname}/> , but after choosing fullName i get the value of emp_id

Comment: Did you forget to add the "select" handler to the autocomplete?

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue but 1) all of the function variables should be local scoped and 2) you can use the shorthand `[]` instead of `arrayNew(1)`.