# Set ID and Text column Name in ColdFusion autoSuggest

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I am using following code in ColdFusion to implement autosuggest.

```
<cfquery name="Site" datasource="Site">
    SELECT ColumnName
    FROM tableName
</cfquery>

<cfinput name="ColumnName"
    type="text"
    autoSuggest="#valueList(Site.ColumnName)#"
    typeahead="true"
    size="40"
    placeholder="ColumnName"/>
```

It works perfectly, Is there any way to bind ID column? I want to submit the ID and have to display the text in auto suggest.

I meant, when we populate the select in html, we have id and text field. But seems to be missing in autosuggest in coldfusion

Is that possible in ColdFusion?

Comment: Honestly I didn't even know about this feature, but I also avoid `<cfinput>` like the plague.  From what I can see, there's no native support to handle for a separating an `id` and `value`.  Personally, I'd choose another route.  Here's a [**blog post**](https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/cfinput-autosuggest/index.html) by Ray Camden showing how to achieve the same result using `<cfinput>`, `html5` and `jQuery UI` autocomplete.. although none of his code snippets show the desired result you're seeking... (to be continued)

Comment: ... (continued)  With that said, I've been able to do an _"autocomplete/autosuggest"_ using jQuery UI that displays a `value` but returns and `id`.  However, I've also used the [**select2**](https://select2.org/) plugin which has this functionality natively baked in. So in my opinion it would be the easiest approach to try.  If I have time later, I'll post a working example code snippet for you.

Comment: I agree about replacing `cfinput` with something more robust, such as jquery's autocomplete. A similar question just came up. If you go that route, this example is easy enough to adapt.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722031/how-to-return-both-an-id-and-text/47723322#47723322